# why does Doctrine ODM (MongoDB) findOneById hit database many times for the same id?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

In our application, within one request, we do many queries of the sort:

$dm->getRepository('Bundle:some_document')->findOneById($id)

My expectation was that when we do second and subsequent calls for some fixed id (say, 1) there should be no actual query to the database and we would get some "in-memory" representation of the document, fetched during the first time.

However, it seems to hit the db over and over again.

Is it an expected behavour or we're missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$repository->findOneById()` is barely wrapping [`$repository->findOneBy($criteria)`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/dde7c42213c3bbf6d9cd9fe4b293714889e09d7c/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/DocumentRepository.php#L194-L197) which may or may not ask for document by its identifier (and there are no optimizations to see if criteria is only an identifier).

If you want to utilize in-memory representation of objects you need to use [`$repository->find()`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/dde7c42213c3bbf6d9cd9fe4b293714889e09d7c/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/DocumentRepository.php#L117) which first tries to [look up your document in the `UnitOfWork`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/dde7c42213c3bbf6d9cd9fe4b293714889e09d7c/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/DocumentRepository.php#L134-L141) and hits database only later if there was no hit.

Comment: thanks for the thorogh answer! that is what I was looking for, also found that in docs http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html "The find() method checks the local in memory identity map for the document before querying the database for the document."